# How to enable Custom Headers option in AWS Amplify console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

This page (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/custom-headers.html) says:

```
To set custom headers for an app in the AWS Management Console
Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amplify console.
Choose the app to set custom headers for.
In the navigation pane, choose App settings, Custom headers.
```

However when I follow the steps, I don't have the "Custom Headers" option.

[image: No Custom Headers option under App Settings]

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The custom headers only applies to the Amplify hosted front-end files. You're not seeing the option appear because you haven't setup front-end hosting yet. Connect your git repo and the options will appear allowing you to add custom headers to RESPONSES returned by the Amplify hosted front-end.